# Реализовать триггер количество тем может быть в диапазоне от 5 до 10

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Вот что я сделал, но ничего не работает

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trig BEFORE INSERT ON topics FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
SET NEW.id=(SELECT count(new.id) FROM topics HAVING count(new.id) BETWEEN 5 and 10); 
END;
```

Помогите пожалуйста я уже который час сижу ничего не получается

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Формулировка вопроса тоже не получилась. Опиши саму задачу - детально и подробно.